# condition for having a positive solution to these linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Consider the following system of linear equations:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\cdot x_{ij}=a_i \text{ for } i=1,\cdots,m$$ 
and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^m c_{ij}\cdot x_{ij}=b_j \text{ for } $j=1,\cdots, n$$
where for all $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$, $a_i$ and $b_j$ are positive, $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j$, and $c_{ij}=1$ or $c_{ij}=0$.

What is the condition for this system of equations having positive solution? Could you also give a simple proof? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\cdot x_j=a_i?$ Moreover, do you ask for a positive solution or all solutions positive?

Comment: Yes, I mean $c_{i1}\cdot x_{i1}+\cdots + c_{in}\cdot x_{in}=a_i$ for all $i=1,\cdots,m$, where $c_{ij} $ is a coefficient. And I want to know the condition for existing a positive solution.